# is this the right way to implement a simple priority queue using double pointer?

Tags: c

im trying to apply linus torvald's idea of "good taste" when he showed an example of removing an entry a singly-linked list using double pointers to eliminate an if statement. I want to know the best way to enqueue and dequeue in a priority queue applying the same idea.

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    typedef struct node node;
    struct node{
        int val;
        node *prev;
    };

    node *head = NULL;

    void enqueue(int val){
        node **focus = &head;
        while((*focus) != NULL && (*focus)->val <= val)
            focus = & (*focus)->prev;
        node *tmp = *focus;                      //is there a way to remove this line
        *focus  = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        **focus = (node){ .val = val, .prev = tmp };
    }

    int dequeue(){
        int ret = head->val;
        node *tmp = head;  
        head = head->prev;
        free(tmp);
        return ret;
    }

    int main(){
        enqueue(20);
        enqueue(11);
        enqueue(4);
        enqueue(6);
        enqueue(9);
        enqueue(8);
        enqueue(27);
        enqueue(44);
        printf("dequeue: %d\n",dequeue());
        printf("dequeue: %d\n",dequeue());
        printf("dequeue: %d\n",dequeue());
        printf("dequeue: %d\n",dequeue());
        printf("dequeue: %d\n",dequeue());
        printf("dequeue: %d\n",dequeue());
        printf("dequeue: %d\n",dequeue());
    }
```

Comment: I urge you to start learning C with something much simpler than code taken from an operating system kernel. And I also advise you that Linus Torvalds' idea of good style is not shared by everyone. You can learn a lot from reading his code, but you can also learn a lot from reading code done in a completely different style ... and what you _should_ do is read both, and form your own opinions.

Comment: With this method, `enqueue()` cost O(n) and `dequeue()` costs O(1).  Other simply approaches cost O(ln(n)) and O(ln(n)) and IMO, is the best way to enqueue and dequeue in a priority queue.  That renders the small optimization of "eliminate an if statement" moot.

Comment: [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) may be a better site for this post if code is at least functionally correct.

Comment: @Alex, who or what text suggested casting the return from `malloc()`?